# Java creating menu and submenu cmd line program

Tags: java, navigation, cmd, stack

For class I am attempting to design a menu driven program which has sub-menu's.  I'm having some logic issues.

Originally I made it so that the switch driven menu's just called each other and the sub-menus would call back to the main menu and so on.  I was told this would eventually blow the stack by going forward with calls and not going backwards.  I would like to confirm this and perhaps sort out my loop logic.

My desire is that when a user hits r or x in the submenu week1 it bounces back and reprints the main menu.  Currently the submenu just reprints with the switch statement not working.  My guess is that the value of main menu is still set to 1, but if i call it and pass a new value aren't I taking the stack 1 deeper?

The first menu.

```
//method to print and navigate the main menu
public void mainMenu(String choice){
    toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/main.txt");

    choice = input.myScanner.nextLine();

    do {

        switch (choice){
            case "1": toBaseNumberSystems.week1();
                      break;
            case "2": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week2.txt");
                      break;
            case "3": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week3.txt");
                      break;
            case "4": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week4.txt");
                      break;
            case "5": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week5.txt");
                      break;
            case "6": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week6.txt");
                      break;
            case "7": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week7.txt");
                      break;
            case "x": choice="x";
                      System.out.println("Goodbye");
                      break;
            default:  System.out.println("The character entered was not understood"
                    + ", please try again");
                      mainMenu(choice);
                      break;
        }
    } while (!"x".equals(choice));
```

Calls only week1 menu, which in turn calls other menus.

```
public void week1(){

    toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/baseNumberSystems.txt");

    choice = input.myScanner.nextLine();
    do{
        switch (choice){

            case "1": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base8.txt");
                      week1Base8();
                      break;
            case "2": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base5.txt");
                      week1Base5();
                      break;
            case "3": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base4.txt");
                      week1Base4();
                      break;
            case "4": toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base2.txt");
                      week1Base2();
                      break;
            case "r": choice="r";
                      break;
            case "x": choice="x";
                      System.out.println("Goodbye");
                      break;
            default:  System.out.println("The character entered wass not understood"
                    + ", please try again");
                      break;
        }
    }while (!"x".equals(choice)&&!"r".equals(choice));
 }

//method to print and control the base8 menu
 public void week1Base8(){
     int base;
    toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base8.txt");

    choice = input.myScanner.nextLine();

    switch (choice){
        case "1": base=8;
                  toBase(base);
                  break;
        case "r": week1();
                  break;
        case "x": choice="x";
                  System.out.println("Goodbye");
                  break;
        default:  System.out.println("The character entered was not understood"
                + ", please try again");
                  break;
    }
 }
 // method to print and control the base5 menu
 public void week1Base5(){
    toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base5.txt");
    int base;
    choice = input.myScanner.nextLine();

    switch (choice){
        case "1": base=5;
                  toBase(base);
                  break;
        case "r": week1();
                  break;
        case "x": choice="x";
                  System.out.println("Goodbye");
                  break;
        default:  System.out.println("The character entered was not understood"
                + ", please try again");
                  break;
     }
 }

 //method to print and control the base4 menu
 public void week1Base4(){
    toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base4.txt");
    int base;
    choice = input.myScanner.nextLine();

    switch (choice){
        case "1": base=4;
                  toBase(base);
        case "r": week1();
                  break;
        case "x": choice="x";
                  System.out.println("Goodbye");
                  break;
        default:  System.out.println("The character entered was not understood"
                + ", please try again");
                  break;
     }
 }

 //method to print and control the base2 menu
 public void week1Base2(){
    toOutput.printMenu("src/datastructures/menus/week1Base2.txt");
    int base;
    choice = input.myScanner.nextLine();

    switch (choice){
        case "1": base=2;
                  toBase(base);
        case "r": week1();
                  break;
        case "x": choice="x";
                  System.out.println("Goodbye");
                  break;
        default:  System.out.println("The character entered was not understood"
                + ", please try again");
                  break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This depends on how the variable "choice" is declared.  From what you tell us, it appears to be a different choice variable in each routine, but it is difficult to tell.  This is why you will often see a request for a *complete* example; in your case, you might need/want to boil your example down to just what is needed to understand and demonstrate your problem.  By cutting some things out of this one, you make it impossible for someone to answer.

Comment: understood.  Will boil it down and reply